# Max Heap is not working as expected

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap, binary-heap

My Java code for Max Heap is not working as expected. Also it is not returning 90 as max when I remove from heap.

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 5/25/16.
 */
public class Heap {
    private int[] heap;
    private int size;
    private int maxSize;


    public Heap(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize=maxSize;
        this.size=0;
        heap=new int[this.maxSize+1];
    }

    private int parent(int pos) {
        return pos/2;
    }

    private int leftChild(int pos) {
        return pos*2;
    }

    private int rightChild(int pos) {
        return pos*2 +1;
    }

    private boolean isLeaf(int pos) {
        if (pos>=size/2 && pos<=size) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void swap(int pos1, int pos2) {
        int tmp=heap[pos1];
        heap[pos1]=heap[pos2];
        heap[pos2]=tmp;
    }


    private void maxHeapify(int pos) {
        if (!isLeaf(pos)){
            if ((heap[pos] < heap[leftChild(pos)]) ||
               (heap[pos] < heap[rightChild(pos)])) {
            if (heap[leftChild(pos)] > heap[rightChild(pos)]) {
                swap(pos , leftChild(pos));
                maxHeapify(leftChild(pos));
            }
            else {
                swap(pos , rightChild(pos));
                maxHeapify(rightChild(pos));
            }

            }

        }
    }

    public void maxHeap() {
        for (int i=(size/2) ; i>=1 ; i--) {
            maxHeapify(i);
        }
    }

    public void insert(int n) {
        heap[++size] = n;
        int tmpLocation = size;
        while (heap[tmpLocation] > heap[parent(tmpLocation)]){
            swap(tmpLocation , parent(tmpLocation));
            tmpLocation=parent(tmpLocation);
        }


    }

    public int remove() {
        int removed = heap[1];
        heap[1] = heap[size-1];
        maxHeapify(1);
        return removed;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i=1 ; i<=(size/2) ; i++) {
            System.out.println("current node is: "+heap[i]+" its left child is " +
                    heap[i*2]+" its right child is "+heap[i*2 +1]);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Heap heap = new Heap(9);
        heap.insert(8);
        heap.insert(18);
        heap.insert(28);
        heap.insert(9);
        heap.insert(12);
        heap.insert(90);
        heap.insert(1);
        heap.insert(87);
        heap.maxHeap();

        heap.print();
        System.out.println("Max is: "+heap.remove());

    }


}
```

Here's the output:

```
current node is: 90 its left child is 90 its right child is 87
current node is: 87 its left child is 28 its right child is 18
current node is: 28 its left child is 12 its right child is 9
current node is: 18 its left child is 8 its right child is 1
current node is: 12 its left child is 0 its right child is 0
Max is: 87

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Also you can see in the first line of output it states left child of 90 is 90 which isn't right. What is that?

```
current node is: 90 its left child is90 its right child is 87
```

UPDATE: When I set the size to 8 I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" current node is: 90 its left child is90 its right child is 87
current node is: 87 its left child is28 its right child is 18
current node is: 28 its left child is12 its right child is 9
current node is: 18 its left child is8 its right child is 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at Heap.print(Heap.java:86)
    at Heap.main(Heap.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

UPDATE: I thought if I change the insert to the following would help but no:

```
public void insert(int n) {
        size++;
        heap[size] = n;
        int tmpLocation = size;
        if (tmpLocation!=1) {
            while (heap[tmpLocation] > heap[parent(tmpLocation)]) {
                swap(tmpLocation, parent(tmpLocation));
                tmpLocation = parent(tmpLocation);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: You've got 9 nodes in your heap - do you get a similar problem with just 8? Or 3? Or 2? etc. Try to your problem so that you can debug it yourself more easily, and it is easier for us to see the issue.

Comment: I get error with setting the Heap size to 8

Comment: yes this is because you index start at 0, this mean 0...8 so you do not have number 9 but you have 9 elements

Comment: in my constructor I have `heap=new int[this.maxSize+1];`

Comment: this perhaps what the arrayindexoutofboundexception says

Comment: Note that when you insert, the heap starts at index 1, but when you print, you are printing from index 0. This may or may not explain the error, but it's a start. Also, you should be checking if size is greater than maxsize before inserting

Comment: I fixed that but seems the problem is in insert.

Comment: @Mona I hope with all comments and answer below you get to the goal.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this line:

```
heap[++size] = n;
```

When you're inserting the first element, you're inserting at position 1, and with the steps you perform, heap[0] & heap[1] will end up having the same values after every insertion. That's why you'll see parent and left child having the same value after every insertion.

For example, when you're inserting the first element, you try to insert at heap[1], and perform swap between heap[0] & heap[1]. The result is you end up with same values in heap[0] & heap[1].

Comment: do you mean I should change it to `size++;
        heap[size] = n;` ?

Comment: How about `heap[size] = n; size++;`? Or `heap[size++] = n;`? They're equivalent.

Comment: because I think you should first increase the size of array and then insert the element at the last allocated slot. @ErickG.Hagstrom

Comment: @MonaJalal The `size` variable doesn't increase the size of the array. It just keeps track of the number of things you have in it. But arrays are zero-relative. So if you increase size from 0 to 1, then insert at position 1, you're placing the new element in a slot that doesn't really exist (in a logical sense). You need to insert, then increment.

Answer (score 1):

In your `insert` and `remove` methods, the code assumes that the root node is at `heap[1]`. But your `print` method thinks that the root node in your heap is at `heap[0]`. That's going to lead you into all kinds of trouble.

Note also that your `remove` method doesn't decrement `size`.

Comment: @MonaJalal: The exception is happening because you're indexing off the end of the array. You have 8 items in your heap. Your heap array has 9 positions (0 through 8). But when you get to the 4th node, it tries to look at the right child: (i*2)+1, which is 9. Boom. Your `print` method has to check to see if the index its computing is smaller than size.